# Cannot resolve overloaded method 'startTimerWithFixedDelay'

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

I do not understand, why I get an overloaded error inside "timers.startTimerWithFixedDelay". I added 3 parameter to ensure to take the right method, but it appears that he also finds the method with just 2 parameters highly attractive.

```
package main
import akka.actor.typed.{ActorSystem, Behavior}
import akka.actor.typed.receptionist.Receptionist
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.Behaviors
import scala.concurrent.duration.{Duration, FiniteDuration, MINUTES}

object Guardian {
  case object Tick

  val start: Behavior[Nothing] =
    Behaviors.setup[Receptionist.Listing] { context =>

      Behaviors.withTimers { timers =>
        timers.startTimerWithFixedDelay(Tick, Tick, FiniteDuration(Duration("3 seconds").toSeconds, MINUTES))
        Behaviors.same
      }

    }.narrow
}

object Application extends App {
  ActorSystem[Nothing](Guardian.start, "system")
}
```

Inside TimerScheduler.scala does it look like, that he can't he decide between:

```
def startTimerWithFixedDelay(msg: T, delay: FiniteDuration): Unit
def startTimerWithFixedDelay(key: Any, msg: T, delay: FiniteDuration): Unit
```

Why is he not taking the one with 3 parameter?

Compiler Error message:

```
[error] ... overloaded method startTimerWithFixedDelay with alternatives:
[error]   (msg: akka.actor.typed.receptionist.Receptionist.Listing,delay: scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration)Unit <and>
[error]   (key: Any,msg: akka.actor.typed.receptionist.Receptionist.Listing,delay: scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration)Unit
```

Answer (score 1):

`Tick` is not a `Receptionist.Listing` so neither version matches.